# changeVisibilityTimeout() call to SQS from Lambda fails without throwing exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda set up with event bridge to receive messages from an SQS with default vis timeout set to 5 minutes.

Inside the lambda, certain messages are supposed to be updated so that the vis timeout is increased to 10 minutes, and then an error is thrown on purpose to resend message (with the 10 min timeout) back to the SQS queue. The code logic in the lambda is as follows:

0. Check that message meets conditions
1. Set Visibility timeout to 10 minutes using synchronous (default) SQS client. Ignore the response object (but it should throw an error on timeout or failure, any response should imply success).
2. Write "New invisibility timeout" to log (this always appears, meaning the call must be completed)
3. Throw an exception to send the message back to the queue

This *does work* 99% of the time but I am seeing edge cases (often during heavy traffic) where the message comes back to the lambda after the default visibility timeout of 5 minutes (and they are not timing out because logs show complete processing). Additional info:

Lambda timeout: 5 minutes

Lambda retries: 2

SQS max receives: 5

Using Java 11

I will try setting the default visibility timeout to 10 minutes to circumnavigate the issue but hope it is a temp fix until I can understand root cause. How can the synchronous call to SQS not work but also not throw any exception?